# gnuplot: How to plot homogeneous spheres in 3D with different diameters?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I want to make a 3D representation of a large number of spheres of different diameter using gnuplot and whose information are in a file called `'data.dat'`. If I do:

```
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 w p lt 7
```

I get a series of points of small dimensions of a homogeneous color. How can I add the **real** size of the spheres (read from the 4th column of the file `'data.dat'`) using the `splot` command? Something like:

```
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3:4 ...
```

Comment: does this answer your question? Any kind of response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since gnuplot 5.4, I guess you have the plotting style `with circles` also in 3D, before, it was limited to 2D plots.

If you have an older gnuplot version you could do something like:

```
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3:4 w p pt 7 ps var notitle
```

This will plot points with variable size. However, you asked for "real" size. You might workaround this with scaling the 4th column with some factor. Something like:

```
Factor = 0.123
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3:($4*Factor) w p pt 7 ps var notitle
```

The following works only for gnuplot >=5.4:

**Code:**

```
### plot with circles in 3D (only for gnuplot >=5.4)
reset session

# create some test data
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:100] {
        print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", rand(0), rand(0), rand(0), rand(0)*0.02+0.02, int(rand(0)*0xffffff))
    }
set print

set view 60,30,1.25
set view equal xyz
set xyplane at 0
set tics 0.2
set style fill solid 0.5

splot $Data u 1:2:3:4:5 w circles lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very useful

Comment: If it answered your question then check it as accepted. If not, what else do you need?

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me where I can put "accepted" to your answer?

Comment: In other words I would like to comunicate that the question I did was resolved by you

Comment: Check the check mark on the top left next to the answer.