# Gnuplot : how to make a gif by plotting one block of data after the other in the same file .dat?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gif

I would like to make a gif from a file `data.dat`:

```
   #x                     y                  z                   radius              color
#set 1
   222.333710          505.354645         -2938.58545          10.0000000          1.00000000         
   854.180481          64.3471069         -2844.13477          12.5992117          53.0000000    
  -109.606003          173.377197         -2975.83960          17.0997639          55.0000000       

#set 2
  0.746170461        -0.868437707         -2876.14355          123.856239          2001.00000    

#set 3   
   1.56590324E-02      6.23370660E-03     -2870.87378          129.126297          4001.00000
```

At each time step I would like to plot:

`splot "data.dat" using 1:2:3:4:5 with circles lc var notitle`

for each set. Meaning at time 1 to plot the set 1, at time 2 the set 2 and so on.

The question of how to plot until a defined line has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row).
But how is it possible to plot until a line one doesn't know ? My idea is to code to plot until a blank line, but I'm open to any suggestion.

Eventually, in order to create the `.gif` I would write :

```
reset session

set term gif size 700,700 animate delay 30 optimize
set output "data.gif"

set xrange [-1000:1000]
set yrange [-1000:1000]
set zrange [-3000:-2500]

do for [a=1:3:1] {

###### code for splot
    
}
set output
```

Comment: Is the data fixed or can it maybe be changed? Your data has a single empty lines, could it maybe changed to a double empty line? For both cases there will be some solution, the latter would probably be easier.

Comment: Yes the data can be changed (It is generated by a Fortran program)

Comment: What would be the solution for data with a double empty line plz ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you separate your sets by two empty lines you can easily address them via `index` (check `help index`). If you don't know the number of sets (or blocks) you can do `stats` (check `help stats`).
You will find the number of blocks in the variable `STATS_blocks` (to see all variables type `show var STATS`). Check the following example as starting point for further optimization.

Attention: the option `optimize` in `term gif` might result in wrong colors (see: [gnuplot: viewing angle dependent colors with 3D circles in GIF terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64568057/7295599))
So, either don't optimize or export all frames as PNG (e.g. via `term pngcairo`) and use another software to create an animated GIF out of them.

**Code:**

```
### create animation from unknown number of sub-blocks
reset session
set term gif size 400,400 animate delay 100
set output "SO68940970.gif"

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    print "#x y z radius color
    SetCount = int(rand(0)*6)+10
    do for [b=1:SetCount] {
        print sprintf("#set%d",b)
        LineCount = int(rand(0)*5)+2
        do for [a=1:LineCount] {
            print sprintf("%g %g %g %g %g", \
              rand(0)*2000-1000,rand(0)*2000-1000,rand(0)*500-3000, \
              rand(0)*100+50, rand(0)*0xffffff)
        }
        if (b<SetCount) { print ""; print "" }  # two empty lines
    }
set print

stats $Data u 1 nooutput
N = STATS_blocks
print N

set xrange [-1000:1000]
set yrange [-1000:1000]
set zrange [-3000:-2500]
set ztics 250
set view equal xyz

set style fill solid 1.0
do for [i=1:N] {
    set title sprintf("Set %d",i)
    splot $Data u 1:2:3:4:5 index i-1 w circles lc rgb var notitle 
}
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]